# How can I add click event to my Raphael pie chart?

Tags: charts, dom-events, raphael, graphael

How can I add click event to my [Raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/) pie chart ?

```
var r = Raphael("holder-1",340, 185); 
pie = r.g.piechart(150,85, 75, values , {legend: labels, legendpos: "east"});
```

I got the answer it is:

```
pie.click(function () {     });
```

Can I pass value to the `onclick` event`? Here can I pass values and labels to` onclick` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the docs for the [node attribute](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#node), you should just be able to attach events as you would any DOM element using it:

```
pie.node.onclick = function () { /* Something */ };
```

Comment: can we pass value to the onclick event  ?