# Click event on raphael pie chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, raphael, pie-chart

I have multiple pie charts which I put them in an array:

```
var pie_array = new Array();
```

Creating pie charts like:

```
for loop{
      pie = r.piechart(48+i*120,40,30,[100],
      {
          colors: ["white"],
          maxSlices: 1
      });
}
```

Now I am adding click event to each pie chart :

```
 $.each(pie_array, function(i, p){
        $(p).click(function(){
            alert(p);
        });
    });
```

But unable to fire an event when I click pie chart...any solutions?

Possible duplicates:
[How to add jquery click event to gRaphael graphics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9767709/how-to-add-jquery-click-event-to-graphael-graphics)

and

[how can i add click evet to my rapahel pie chart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6013801/how-can-i-add-click-evet-to-my-rapahel-pie-chart)

but none of the solutions work

I even used:

```
 //below one says click event on unknown element..I printed p and it raphael set
 $.each(pie_array, function(i, p){
        p.click(function(){
            alert(p);
        });
    }); 

and

$.each(pie_array, function(i, p){
        p.node.oclick = function(){
            alert(p);
        };
    });
```

but no progress

Comment: Can you share your solution for others that have the same problem?

Comment: @Chris: do you know to retrieve attributes like color, stroke, radius of pie chart

Comment: yes sure:

yes sure $.each(pie_array, function(i) { this.click(function () { alert("hello"); }); });

http://jsfiddle.net/zFCur/

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are not adding the created pie charts to your array.

Comment: I was adding it to the array but the problem was different you cannot attach click event with any solution specified in the question all of them are wrong